# Making Sense of Method of Characteristics Solution Geometry

Tags: geometry, partial-differential-equations, 3d, characteristics, transport-equation

How can I make sense of the following surface as insight into understanding the method of characteristics?

[image]

The partial differential equation this initially came from was $2xu_x + u_y = 0$, which has solutions $u = f(xe^{-2y})$ for arbitrary functions $f$.  I don't know what boundary conditions produce this particular choice of $f$; I just whimsically picked some functions to graph.

I can *almost* believe that $\begin{bmatrix}2x \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is tangential to the "main" lines on this graph, the lines which hug the planes $x = 0$ (for negative $y$) and $y = 0$, although the main lines *do* have a slight oscillating pattern which seems out of place.  However the lines on the stalagmites and stalactites certainly do not obey this tangency condition; they wrap the entire way around, while $x$ and $y$ vary only slightly in these regions.

Comment: Looks like Bryce Canyon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is oscillating like crazy for $y<0$, and your picture doesn't bear any resemblance to the actual graph, since the resolution is way too low. Try something like `Plot3D[Cos[Sinh[x Exp[-2 y]]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 400]` and you might begin to get some feeling for what it really looks like:

[image: Mathematica plot]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Hans's plot, it might be easier to understand a 2D plot. I've superimposed the characteristics (blue) $xe^{-2y}=k$, $k\in\{-100,-99,\dots,100\}$ with the graph (green) of your chosen function $\cos(\sinh(x))$:
[image: top down plot]
Note that $\cos(\sinh(x))=\cos(\sinh(x e^{-2(0)}))$ is the $y=0$ cross-section of $u(x,y) = \cos(\sinh(xe^{-2y}))$. By following the characteristic lines down, you are squeezing this graph into  smaller and smaller regions. At $y=-1/2$, the portion of $\cos(\sinh(x))$ that I've plotted ($x\in[-10,10]$) is shrinked  into $[-4,4]$, and then it keeps getting smaller exponentially: For example, everything that is above the lowest characteristic curve $ xe^{-2y}=\pm 100$ is squeezed into a tiny interval at $y=-4$. More precisely, the graph, over the region $x\in[-100,100]$, which is already incredibly squiggly, is squeezed into
$$ |x|e^8\le 100\quad  \text{i.e.}\quad x\in[-0.0335,0.0335].$$
Hopefully, this gives you a feel for why your plot wasn't accurate.